# Compiling many test files in parallel

Tags: c++, testing, compilation, architecture

I have a catch2 test bench for a header-only library I am developing. The test bench consists of a header test file for each header file in the library. I compile all of the tests by creating a `test_main.cpp` file which basically includes all of the test headers.  The file layout is depicted below.

```
include/
-- f1.hpp
-- f2.hpp
...
-- fn.hpp
test/
-- f1_test.hpp
-- f2_test.hpp
...
-- fn_test.hpp
-- test_main.cc
-- test_root.cc
```

I have a significant number of files to test, and am typically only working on one at a time. However, whenever I need to recompile, I have to start the entire process over since `test_main.cc` is the only target. This also doesn't allow me to build in parallel.

How can I split the build up into smaller targets so that I can build in parallel and only have to rebuild a small part of the test bench when recompiling?

The corresponding part of the Makefile is bellow:

```
TEST_OBJS = ${BUILD_DIR}/test_main.o ${BUILD_DIR}/test_root.o
${BUILD_DIR}/test_main.o: ext/catch2.hpp ${TEST_DIR}/test_main.cc 
    mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}
    ${CXX} ${FLAGS} ${INCLUDES} ${TEST_DIR}/test_main.cc -c -o $@
${BUILD_DIR}/test_root.o: ext/catch2.hpp ${HEADERS} ${ALGORITHM_HEADERS} ${SRCS} 
    mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}
    ${CXX} ${FLAGS} ${INCLUDES} ${TEST_DIR}/test_root.cc -c -o $@ 
tests: ${TEST_OBJS}
    mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}
    ${CXX} ${TEST_OBJS} -o ${BUILD_DIR}/tests
```

`test_root.cc` is just a list of `#include "fi_test.hpp"` and `test_main.cc` is just

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch2.hpp"
```

Each of the test files looks like this:

```
#include "test_root.cc"
TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_TEST_CASE() {
// stuff 
}
```

Comment: The obvious solution is to extract the useful parts from `test_main.cpp` into another header so that you can build individual tests as individual source files.  Then only compile the one you're working on.  If you think about it, having one source file that includes loads and loads of headers still means only one source file.

Comment: @paddy Yea I figured since including essentially just copies the headers in. I’m just not sure how to build the individual headers as source files and have them all then included in the main.

Comment: Well we're not sure either, since you've shown no code.

Comment: I've added the code, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Seems to me this is a fundamental limitation of any header-only library.